# No response obtained while implementing CORS

Tags: http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

I am using CORS for cross-domain talk on my website. Although, the response header as shown in the pic,  seems fine to me, yet, I am not receiving any response. Its still blank or returns with response. Can anyone predict the error in my approach, seeing the attached image ?

At server side, I am using this snippet

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
```

While at the client side , I have :-

```
function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
try {
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch(err1) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (err2) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (err3) {
req = false;
}
}
}
return req;
}

var http899 = getXMLHTTPRequest();

http899.open("GET", modurl, true);
http899.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
http899.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse899;
http899.send(null);
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the expire time. Its of 1981. Can that be an issue ?

Comment: Seems like similar problem here: http://serverfault.com/questions/446152/litespeed-enable-access-control-allow-origin-no-response-header-on-cors-request

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy AFter resolving my issue, I wrote this.. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964178/implementing-cross-domain-communication-between-sites-through-cors-using-php-and/11964339#11964339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily a complete answer, but I think some browsers don't accept multiple entries in the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. I don't know if Firefox is one of them.

Maybe try copying the request's "Origin" header into the response's "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" if it's in the list of origins you want to accept?

Comment: Yeah, I removed that repeated entry, still facing the same issue !

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with my server. When I tried the same code on different server, it worked ! I was using shared hosting , where it was disabled by the service provider.