# Implementing cross domain communication between sites through CORS using PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cross-domain, cors

After days of browsing on web and trying every possible thing, I came to know about there were issues with my host server. It was disabled by my host server. So, I thought of posting my code on Stackoverflow, so that , no one else on SO loses time as I did.

The code snippet works perfectly fine on IE, Safari, Mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: What was disabled by your host server? What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know exactly, how it was blocked. But my service provider confirmed that they don't support this, which was later proved , when the same snippet worked on different server. Also the article at http://enable-cors.org/ tells how to check whether its enabled on ur server or not. That proves that it can be disabled, don't know how though. Please enlighten me if you can guess the reason for the same.

Comment: It isn't "disabled" or "enabled", you simply need to send the CORS headers. This is mentioned on any CORS tutorial worth reading on the web. For example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Comment: So, what else can be the issue, if, the same code worked for other server ?

Comment: @Esailija Has it got something to do with the server then ? Because all the requests on that server were simply being cancelled by the server

Comment: @PrashantSingh Probably the server was misconfigured somehow if it doesn't take requests.

Comment: My host with litespeed is having the same problem.  This same piece of junk can't deny/allow by domain either http://serverfault.com/questions/446152/litespeed-enable-access-control-allow-origin-no-response-header-on-cors-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript Code for the client side

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

// function for making an object for making AJAX request

function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
try {
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch(err1) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (err2) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (err3) {
req = false;
}
}
}
return req;
}

var http899 = getXMLHTTPRequest();
function searchFabIndia() {

var myurl = "http://my2nddomain.com/yebhi.php";
myRand = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999999999);
var modurl = myurl+"?rand="+myRand;
http899.open("GET", modurl, true);
http899.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse899;
http899.send(null);
}

function useHttpResponse899() {
if (http899.readyState == 4) {
if(http899.status == 200) {
 // do all processings with the obtained values / response here
}
}
}

</script>

<body onload='searchFabIndia();'>
```

Part of the code required on the server side. You need to set the origin(referrers) who can ask for the page content, allow methods and headers. These settings can be stored either in the .htaccess file together for all the files on the 2nd domain to which you are making request, or, you can put them in your specific PHP file as shown:-

```
    <?php
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
        header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 18000");
// Put it in your PHP file
    ?>
```

OR else , you can specify these settings for the entire domain/sub-domain together by mentioning the same in your .htaccess file as shown :-

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods : POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
</FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
```

Also not that the wildcard allowance to all the referrers can be sometimes unnecessary , so, in that case you can specify the specific domain/sub-domain by naming them , each of them separated by comma(,) as shown

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://abc.com,http://def.com,http://ghi.com
```

Please comment in case you face some difficulty in implementing any of these. You can see live demo of what I mentioned [here](http://compare.buyhatke.com/products/apple-ipod-touch)

Comment: You can't use `http899` inside the scope of `useHttpResponse899()`

Comment: Sry, my mistake, that should be out of that function ! Check the new solution !!

Comment: So does this bypass your host's restriction?

Comment: Is this included in jQuery $.ajax?

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy Implementing CORS doesn't depend upon how you implement ajax request, but it depends on your server configurations. The Ajax request would be exactly similar to the normal ajax request, only the file you wish to access should have the required permissions. What problem are you facing exactly ?

Comment: My host has LiteSpeed, and they can't figure out why I'm getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.  My settings are all properly set in my .htaccess because I see them in the response headers.  My guess is that this is just another limitation of LiteSpeed.  Just found out they don't allow/deny by domain in htaccess either.  Here's my issue:  http://serverfault.com/questions/446152/litespeed-enable-access-control-allow-origin-no-response-header-on-cors-request

Comment: If the above process doesn't work for you, I am pretty sure, its a server issue. I had already been in such a situation.