# SSL CORS not working with Zend Guard

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, ssl, cors

I've added everything to my Apache htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Depth
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: User-Agent
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-File-Size
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: If-Modified-Since
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-File-Name
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mysite.com 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mysite.com
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

I added this to my jquery $.ajax:

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

Absolutely nothing works.

I'm doing $.ajax with

```
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json'
```

I thought by setting all of those headers above, I could do json not jsonp (please no jsonp.  anything but jsonp.  i can't get success to fire.  please.god.no)

I'm at my limits.  I'm getting the good ole

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mysite.com/aDirectory/aSecureFile.php. Origin http://mysite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Please help.  I'm dying here.  I promise I've looked everywhere, oh, have I looked everywhere.

Many thanks in advance!

**Clarity**

My headers are all coming across.  I can see them in my response headers, but I'm still getting the above error.  Is the server blocking?  The browser?  Is there something special I have to do to do https?  Is there another setting on Apache I have to set to allow CORS?  Is my jQuery $.ajax correct?  Aside from data and success and error (and the URL always being https), that's all I'm doing to the jQuery $.ajax.

Thanks again!

**new**

[Cross Domain AJAX preflighting failing Origin check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423983/cross-domain-ajax-preflighting-failing-origin-check?rq=1) didn't help (I don't think).  Added

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ORIGINS
```

(adjusting for sets and adds).  All response headers coming down the pipe.

**newer**

Added these

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept
```

still nothing

**REQUEST HEADERS**

Do these help?

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://mysite.com
Referer:http://mysite.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
```

**PHP**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mysite.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mysite.com");
```

**RESPONSE HEADERS CLARITY**

The RESPONSE HEADERS are coming through on all normal requests not the cross domain https ajax.

**Server**

CentOS 5.8, Apache 2.2.2, PHP 5.3, cPanel, WHM

**Fine, if PHP not executing**

So, in my haste, I copied slashingweapon's cors.php directly without php tags.  I made a test page with $.ajax using the settings above.

It worked (as in there were no errors when the ajax fired) complete with response headers.  As soon as I added the  tags to the PHP, the error happened.  I checked to see if it was a directory issue, putting it in both root and a subdirectory, fine as long as PHP is not executing.

Does this mean anything to anyone?

Is there a PHP setting that needs to be flipped?

Thanks to all for grinding this out with me!

**We have a heartbeat**

It looks like multiple arguments in the htacess craps my server out.  I reduced all those options above to this (which is fine for me, but I pity da fool who needs more):

`<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mysite.com
       Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>`

All I put in the PHP was

```
echo "this works at least":
```

And that came in the response.  Once I figure out what's causing my PHP to fail, I'll post it.

Again, thanks all!

**Zend Guard the problem?**

Sooooooooo, sorry guys.  Forgot to add that my site's running Zend Guard.  Have a feeling that's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the client tries to do a CORS request it first sends a "preflight" request to make sure the server supports CORS.  If the preflight request passes, then the real request will be send.

Your server needs to send the right responses to CORS requests.  I have a [CORS PHP](https://gist.github.com/2202603) gist that shows how to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping.  About to test your PHP now.  Do I have to add anything special to $.ajax?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to make sure that mod_headers is enabled

```
a2enmod headers
```

Then, as a test, you can set the origin as a wild card in your .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

I'm seeing docs with and without the colon (:) and I don't have a system to test on right now so you might play with that as well.

Of course after enabling the headers, you will need to bounce apache.

Comment: Do you have CentOS solution, too?

Comment: Add the following line to your httpd.conf file "LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so" which might be in there already.

Comment: My headers are coming across.  The error above keeps happening.

Comment: Can you give the link to your website. Sometimes that may help.

Comment: It's still in development.  I'd rather not open it up until it's ready.  :/

Comment: I'm looking at an application that I built using cors. In my response (I'm using php) have a `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` and a `header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");` obviously this is just for testing but it helped me move along with building.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy Copy paste this exactly as it is given without thinking anything and find out if you are getting a response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964178/implementing-cross-domain-communication-between-sites-through-cors-using-php-and/11964339#11964339

Comment: Copied exactly, changing the the pathe of var myurl.  Same error as in question.  You think it's a server problem?  Thank-you very much for your help.