# Angular 2 jwt authentication header does not work

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am having an issue with my jwt authentication. 

 I am trying to get a list of templates from my rest api, but when I try to access the header 'Authorization', the value is null.
Here is my code:

```
loadTemplates(): Observable<Template[]> {
  const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': this.authService.getPrefix() + this.authService.getLocalToken()})
  return this.httpService.post(this.baseURL + 'api/templates/short',  {headers: headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error));
}
```

The Prefix and also the Token is set, I can see them when I log them in the console.

The probem is, when I look in the developer console in Chrome, I can see the 
   Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization 
But it is null in the backend. (Tried to log the value of the header 'Authorization')
When I try to access the backend via Postman it does work. With the same prefix + token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, that you forgot to handle so called 'preflight' request on the server side. Try to add something like this [this filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809528/spring-boot-cors-filter-cors-preflight-channel-did-not-succeed).