# Spring Boot : CORS Issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I am using Spring Boot version 2.0.2Release.
Below is my security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.mk")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/index.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"*").authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

I am unable to invoke any API (including login which is permitAll) because of CORS issue.

On Browser I am getting (It works with Postman, since CORS check is not made there)

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/myurl: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although Spring security provides a way to configure CORS in http configurer, there's a much cleaner approach to add CORS filter to the application-

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyCORSFilter implements Filter {


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```

Ordering the filter with highest precedence makes sure that MyCORSFilter implementation of `javax.servlet.Filter` is the first one in the chain. Hope this helps

Comment: This one works for me. with the only issue being that this is being invoked multiple times in same request.

Comment: not the css/icons etc because they are hosted on different server, but let me check

Comment: @MohitKanwar Try to use OncePerRequestFilter , 
public class CustomFIlter extends OncePerRequestFilter

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821971/8092044

Answer (score 8):

There is no need of adding any additional `Filters` or `WebMvcConfigurer`. The main problem is `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` does not present in the header because `corsConfigurationSource` does not add the necessary configuration to get the relevant CORS response headers. Hence, the below missing configurations have to be added when we configure `CorsConfigurationSource`

```
configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
```

We have to configure cors **`CorsConfigurationSource`**  as below

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                 .....
  }

 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        //the below three lines will add the relevant CORS response headers
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

If anyone facing `CORS` issue with Spring Boot 2.4.0 plus versions when having the following combination then refer to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65798063/3303074)

> `CorsConfigurationSource#setAllowedOrigins` value as **`*`**

and

> `CorsConfigurationSource#setAllowCredentials` value as `true`

Comment: Why do you `addAllowedOrigin("*")` after you've `setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"))`?

Comment: yes, you can remove the following `addAllowedOrigin("*")` as we have already added `setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"))`, I added just to illustrate multiple option is possible to add the origins

Comment: But if you remove these duplicate lines then it's the same code as in OP's question, no?
I don't get it, I have my config like you said, but still preflight has "No Allow Origin Header"...

Comment: I get an error When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.

Answer (score 7):

Checkout this guide from Spring:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

There are few ways to add CORS support in Spring Boot.

Using global configuration:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
}
```

And using `@CrossOrigin` annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so I realized that it was deprecated.  If you look on baeldung it has how to do it the new way since they updated webmvcconfigurer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins(frontDomain);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use @EnableWebMvc I don't think .  If you have that, spring boot won't auto configure the mvc.

Comment: Also, what's the point of cors if you are going to allow all origins which is what your code says.

Comment: You are correct regarding allowing all origins, this is a sample code that I am using for testing.

Comment: Ok, I figured something like that was going on.