# Failed request when calling secured API with JWT

Tags: angular, jwt, postman

I have a question about failed request when I call my secured API (spring boot).
**Front app (Angular)**
First, I call my /authenticate endpoint API to get the JWT (all is ok). 
I put the JWT on the header request with Bearer in Authorization attribute, and when I call the protected API element with this JWT, I get a failed error.
like this : 
[Failed request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPCIF.png)

**Postman :**
When I test my API with Postman, All is OK.
I can get the JWT, and put it in the header's request postman, and I get my /elements

Any idea why doesn't work with my angular app ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Check that it's not a CORS issue. If not, check in the network tab that headers are sent correctly. And show us how you send headers

Comment: It has probably to do with CORS

Comment: Did u see the logs? For errors.

Comment: you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809528/spring-boot-cors-filter-cors-preflight-channel-did-not-succeed?fbclid=IwAR2yzyYDZNnu6goJUR9RfyUmNI3yZIGAKWG-Ngm--Y75bjJXLja1EQ9N4pY

Comment: Hello gays, the above link was help me :)
Tahnks for all :)