# How to make proxy work on Angular 2 with webpack-dev-server configuration?

Tags: angular, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I have an app in Angular 2 (2.4.1) and a server with the following:

Front-end runs on localhost:8081 and has:

```
node v6.17.1
npm  v3.10.10
```

Among devDependencies in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...,
    "typescript": "2.1.1",
    "webpack": "1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    ...
}

"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "serverprod": "npm run server:prod",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --config config/webpack.develop.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "webpack-dev-server -d --config config/webpack.prod.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hot",
    "start": "npm run server",
    ...
}
```

In webpack.config.js:

```
 devServer: {
        headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        },
        port: METADATA.port, //8081
        host: METADATA.host, //localhost
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000
        },
        outputPath: helpers.root('dist'),
        stats: 'errors-only', // hide all the verbose info
    },
```

And I call API as:

```
export class Api {
    constructor(protected http: Http) {

    }

    public call() {
        ...
        http.post("/api", requestBody, {headers: headers})
            .map(...
    }
}
```

My server is on localhost:8080 and the endpoint I am trying to reach is on localhost:8080/api

Now, when I start the app with `npm start` I can see in logs this:

```
...
70% 3/3 build modules[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://localhost:8080
 http://localhost:8081/
webpack result is served from /home/
...
```

And when the API is called I can see in browser console this:

```
zone.js:1561 POST http://localhost:8081/api 404 (Not Found)
```

Meaning, that it does not proxy the request to port 8080, as I want it to, but instead tries to reach the API on port 8081 and fails.

How do I make it proxy the request?

I tried t configure it with "/api*", "/api/*", "/api**", "/api/**", it does not change the behavior.
The app does not use "ng", does not have angular.json, so other approaches to proxying are not possible as I understand.

Could it be the "zone.js" issue?

Why does it write the `http://localhost:8081/` after `Proxy created: /api  ->  http://localhost:8080` when starting the app, could it mean overriding proxy target address?

Comment: Most probably proxy works, in browser console you see `POST http://localhost:8081/api 404 (Not Found)` because browser does request to `http://localhost:8081/api`, browser does not know that it's being proxied after that. Please check that you really has an endpoint that handles `POST requests` by `http://localhost:8080/api` url. To check that, you can make a POST request from any tool (like `Postman` or something) by `http://localhost:8080/api` url.

Comment: You are right, my API context was broken. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, no problem