# CORS preflight did not succeed with Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, http-status-code-500

I have a Spring Boot application using version 2.7.6 and Kotlin.
I have a frontend built with Angular and I'm trying to send requests to my backend.
I use Spring Security in my project.
I am having trouble setting a CORS configuration to allow my Angular frontend to send requests to the backend while developping both.

From my research online, it seems like I need a CORS configuration to allow the two to communicate while in development mode.

This is the CORS configuration I have added to my project:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class CorsConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
    }
}
```

This is how I set up the CORS configuration in my `WebSecurityConfig`:

```kotlin
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig @Autowired constructor(
    val authTokenFilter: AuthTokenFilter
){

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
        http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()

        http
            .addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter::class.java)
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

I have tried using the `@CrossOrigin` annotation on the controller level like specified [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors) but it doesn't seem to work either.

I have found [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2215) similar issue and the proposed solutions doesn't work either.

I have also tried both solutions provided by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809528/spring-boot-cors-filter-cors-preflight-channel-did-not-succeed/36821971#36821971) to a similar issue but it still doesn't work.

My Spring Boot application doesn't log any error.
The only thing I can see is in my developer tools on my navigator like so:
[image]

The request passes through via Postman and it seems like I need to allow `OPTIONS` preflight. I have tried adding them to my `SecurityConfig` doing `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()` but it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I should configure the CORS to be disabled throughout my application?

Comment: @jub0bs I tried with the `cors()` call before the `authorizeRequests()` and it doesn't seem to be the root issue, I will keep it in that order from now on.

Comment: I see that the preflight response has status code 500. Do you know why? You need to fix that, because preflight responses must have a 2xx status code to succeed.

Comment: @Hadestructhor Are you sure that your `authTokenFilter` isn't throwing any exception?

Comment: I have no stacktrace from my authTokenFilter